# change php echo font and color

Tags: javascript, php, css

Is there a way to enlarge and change the color text in the echoed data in this function?

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo    "$(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load('somepage.php')
        }, 3000);
    });";
echo '</script>'
?>
```

Comment: Change color and size of which text? The text inside your php file?

Comment: `#show { color: red; font-size: 20pt; }`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj change the color and size of the data been loaded inside the function.. coming from `somepage.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo    "$(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load('somepage.php').css({
                'font-size': '18px',
                'color: '#F00'
            });
        }, 3000);
    });";
echo '</script>'
?>
```

Or, the best way, CSS:

```
#show {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. thou, I don't understand the downvotes for simply asking a question.

Comment: On your next questions, try to be more specific. For example, what kind of information is loaded into the `div` you want to style.